# sending high and low priority messages with a discord bot

Tags: discord.py

Discord limits bots to 5 actions per server per 5 second period - so it's important that your bot responds to urgent things as fast as possible, even if that means deprioritising other things.

My first attempt to deal with this is these two commands (notably the first one uses the time module)

```
@bot.command()
async def low_priority_count(ctx, num: int):

    for i in range(num):
        time.sleep(1)
        await ctx.send("low priority "+str(i))

@bot.command()
async def high_priority_count(ctx, num: int):

    for i in range(num):
        await ctx.send("high priority "+ str(i))
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

My idea was that if you call $high_priority_count 20 the loop would quickly send messages containing the numbers 0-19 although discord wil ltake some time to print them out. As a result I expected that if you called $low_priority_count 20 you would get the low prioirty messages coming after the high priority messages.

instead you get them intercolated. Here is an appended version of the messagse on a text channel:

```
User:      $high_priority_count 20
Bot:       high priority 0
           high priority 1
           high priority 2
           ...
           high priority 9
User:      $low_priority_count 20
Bot:       high priority 10
           low priority 0
           high priority 11
           low priority 1
           high priority 12
           low priority 2
           ...
           high priority 19
           low priority 9
           low priority 10
           low priority 11
           low priority 12
           ...
           low priority 20
```

Why is the bot sending the messages together? and is there a way of making sure that it sends the high priority messages before it sends the low priority ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `time.sleep` which is a blocking function, you shouldn't use it within your asynchronous code. If you use `asyncio.sleep` everything should work as you intended

```py
import asyncio

@bot.command()
async def low_priority_count(ctx, num: int):
    for i in range(num):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await ctx.send("low priority "+str(i))


@bot.command()
async def high_priority_count(ctx, num: int):
    for i in range(num):
        await ctx.send("high priority "+ str(i))
```

You should also add a delay in the `high_priority_count` command, when testing the code I've hit the ratelimit a couple of times.

EDIT:

Answering your comment, this is a more complicated, you can use [Synchronization Primitives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html). [`asyncio.Semaphore`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Semaphore) should work

```py
bot.priority_semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore()

@bot.command()
async def high_priority_count(ctx, count: int):
    await bot.priority_semaphore.acquire()
    for i in range(count):
        await ctx.send(f"High priority {i}")

    bot.priority_semaphore.release()


@bot.command()
async def low_priority_count(ctx, count: int):
    await bot.priority_semaphore.acquire():
    for i in range(count):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await ctx.send(f"High priority {i}")

    bot.priority_semaphore.release()
```

Sadly if you invoke the `low_priority_count` command first, it will first send the low priority messages, I cannot think a way of first sending the high priority messages if the low ones are first invoked.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to help but not solve the problem. With that code, I get moer high priority messages coming through for each low prioirity message that comes through, but suprisingly there is still a mixture. Here is the messages from the text channel with high priority abreviated to hp and low priority abreviated to lp

Comment: User: $high_priority_count 20

Bot:
hp 0
hp 1
hp 2
hp 3
hp 4
 
User: $low_priority_count 20

Bot:
hp 5
lp 0
hp 6
hp 7
hp 8
hp 9
lp 1
hp 10
hp 11
hp 12
hp 13
lp 2
hp 14
hp 15
hp 16
hp 17
lp 3
hp 18
hp 19
lp 4
lp 5
lp 6
lp 7 ...

Comment: Oh so you want to first send the high priority messages and then the low priority? I thought you wanted them interlaced, let me edit my answer

Comment: Thanks so much - if the situation where i have to pause one command whilst another runs comes up I'll ask another question!

Comment: Alright, you can also DM me on discord if you need any help, `kwieeciol#6035`

Comment: Thanks, you are probably the most helpful person i interact with on this site - so I really appreciate it! (freind request sent)